# Axis2 Send CDATA Value as Sting in Request Tag

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I have to consume a SOAP web-service. I'm using axis2. I have generated the stub. The problem is there is a 
element which I need to send the value in the CDATA tag. i.e  as a string containing the CDATA itself.

How can this be achieved. Code listed below.

Service request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<tem:processCustomsRequest>
<tem:Bank_Code>7083</tem:Bank_Code>
<tem:Branch_Code>747</tem:Branch_Code>
<tem:Institution_ID>001</tem:Institution_ID>
<tem:Transaction_Type>01</tem:Transaction_Type>
<tem:Transaction_ID>7083001120918468</tem:Transaction_ID>
<tem:Date_Time>20180911080153</tem:Date_Time>
    <tem:Dynamic_Field_Data>
        <![CDATA[  <dynamic_fields_data>
        <parameter key="OfficeCode" value="CBBD1"  />
        <parameter key="AmountToBePaid" value="3222602"  />
        <parameter key="RegistrationYear" value="2018"  />
        <parameter key="RegistrationSerial" value="I"  />
        <parameter key="RegistrationNumber" value="178326"  />
        <parameter key="MeanOfPayment" value="10"  />
        <parameter key="Branch" value=""  />
        <parameter key="CheckReference" value="258"  />
        <parameter key="CompanyCode" value="1749176127000"  />
        <parameter key="Declarantcode" value="2040081407000" />
        </dynamic_fields_data>]]>
    </tem:Dynamic_Field_Data>
</tem:processCustomsRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Code from java implementaion.

```
processCustomsRequest.setTransaction_ID(tranId);
processCustomsRequest.setTransaction_Type(tranType);

processCustomsRequest.setDynamic_Field_Data(dynFieldData);

ProcessCustomsRequestResponse processCustomsRequestResponse = s.processCustomsRequest(processCustomsRequest);
```

`dynFieldData` should be the string value

```
"<![CDATA[  <dynamic_fields_data>
        <parameter key="OfficeCode" value="CBBD1"  />
        <parameter key="AmountToBePaid" value="3222602"  />
        <parameter key="RegistrationYear" value="2018"  />
        <parameter key="RegistrationSerial" value="I"  />
        <parameter key="RegistrationNumber" value="178326"  />
        <parameter key="MeanOfPayment" value="10"  />
        <parameter key="Branch" value=""  />
        <parameter key="CheckReference" value="258"  />
        <parameter key="CompanyCode" value="1749176127000"  />
        <parameter key="Declarantcode" value="2040081407000" />
        </dynamic_fields_data>]]>"
```

I have created using ADB. How this can be achieved?

Comment: Yes, use the same string `<![CDATA[<dynamic_fields_data>.......       </dynamic_fields_data>]]>` you have mentioned, it should work.

Comment: @Red Boy Thanks for the response but the value is being sent out without the CDATA, i.e as the string "<dynamic_fields_data>
        ... 
        <parameter key="Declarantcode" value="2040081407000" />
        </dynamic_fields_data>"